# What is the right way to set header in the youtube-dl config file

Tags: quoting, youtube-dl

I checked the documentation:

```
--add-header FIELD:VALUE         Specify a custom HTTP header and its value,
                                 separated by a colon ':'. You can use this
                                 option multiple times
```

However, it is not clear to me and probably not to [some other people as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56608873/how-do-i-use-youtube-dls-add-header-option).

So, I asked this question on their [support page](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/27569). At best the answer was ambiguous to me. However, the hint was to:

> Read FAQ on your shell.

So, what is the right way to set header in the `youtube-dl.conf` file:

```
--add-header Accept-Encoding:"identity;q=1, *;q=0"
```

or,

```
--add-header 'Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0'
```

or,

```
--add-header "Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0"
```

Comment: That answer on GitHub is nonsense since the configuration file is not read by a shell. It's read by youtube-dl. It's entirely up to the youtube-dl developers how the file is parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging through the code (I haven't verified empirically), the configuration files are parsed in [`_readOptions`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/2020.12.29/youtube_dl/options.py#L42) which calls [`compat_lex_split`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/479cc6d5a166dc2f250687616041c9f3b36c80b4/youtube_dl/compat.py#L2666) which calls the function [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) from the Python standard library in POSIX mode. This is an approximation of shell quoting (and with enough differences that reading the documentation of a shell would be misleading). The rules in a nutshell are:

- An unquoted `#` starts a comment which runs until the end of the line.
- Unquoted whitespace separates words.
- Backslash quotes the next character: backslash+character stands for that second character.
- Inside single quotes `'…'`, all characters are taken literally.
- Inside double quotes `"…"`, a backslash quotes the next character only if it's a backslash or a double quote, everything else is taken literally.

Here are some examples:

- `foo '' bar` → `foo`, empty word, bar
- `foo#bar` → `foo`
- `"foo  bar"baz` → `foo  barbaz`
- `"\f\\"` → `\f\`
- `'\f\\'` → `\f\\`
- `\f\\` → `f\`

And all of the following are equivalent:

```
--add-header Accept-Encoding:"identity;q=1, *;q=0"
--add-header Accept-Encoding:'identity;q=1, *;q=0'
--add-header Accept-Encoding:identity;q=1,\ *;q=0
--add-header 'Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0'
--add-header "Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0"
```

Comment: I am sorry that I could only give you one tick and one upvote.